# Restore a Content Database from spbr0000 using Powershell

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, content-database, restore

I have took a backup of our live content database using the following command:-

```
Backup-SPFarm -Directory  \\servername\f  -BackupMethod Full -Item WSS_Content_ea05******15e8  -Verbose
```

which generated these two compenents:-

1. spbrtoc xml file
2. spbr0000 folder which contain a list of .bak files.

now i want to restore this content database on our test server ? but not sure that i should specify inside these parameters for the `Restore-SPFarm` command:-

- -Directory. should it be referencing the folder or certain file inside the spbr0000 folder?
- -BackupId. should this be a random number ?

**EDIT**
now i try running this command on test machine:-

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory T:\fileserver\farm -RestoreMethod new -Item WSS_Content_copyLive  -Verbose
```

where the `T:\fileserver\farm` is a folder which contain the backup folder spbr0000.. and i gave the content database a new name `WSS_Content_copyLive`, but this script raised the following error:-

```
Verbose: Using directory: T:\fileserver\farm\spbr0000\.
Verbose: Initializing objects for restore.
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Adding WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 to Restore list.
Verbose: Searching for item: Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Applicatio
n\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8.
Verbose: Found 1 item(s).
Verbose: Adding WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 to Restore list.
Verbose: Searching for item: WSS_Content_copyLive.
Verbose: Found 0 item(s).
Restore-SPFarm : Item WSS_Content_copyLive not found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Restore-SPFarm -Directory T:\fileservert\farm -RestoreMethod new -item
WSS_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...dletRestoreFarm:
   SPCmdletRestoreFarm) [Restore-SPFarm], SPException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletRestoreF
   arm

VERBOSE: Leaving ProcessRecord Method of Restore-SPFarm.
VERBOSE: Leaving EndProcessing Method of Restore-SPFarm.
```

**EDIT-2**
now i tried defining the same content database name as on the live server:-

```
Restore-SPFarm -Directory T:\fileserver\farm -RestoreMethod new -Item  WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8  -Verbose
```

i got these on the cmd window:-

```
verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Initializing SPPersistedObject State
Verbose: Adding WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 to Restore list.
Verbose: Searching for item: Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Applicatio
n\SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8.
Verbose: Found 1 item(s).
Verbose: Adding WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 to Restore list.
Verbose: Searching for item: WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8.
Verbose: Found 1 item(s).
Change location/name for: Farm\Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application\
SharePoint - 80\WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8
        Log file location: (default: L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SPS\MSSQL\Data
):
```

now i went to my dev machine database,, but i can not find the database insdie the sql server? also from the output i find this

```
L:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SPS\MSSQL\Data
```

but on my dev this folder does not exists, it is the folder inside the live .. can anyone advice on this please ?

Answer (score 1):

You should mentioned the folder name and restore job will pick it up, make sure all the files exist in that folder( mxl and bak)

`BackupFolder>` is the name and path for the backup folder where the content database was backed up.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748604.aspx

**BackupId(it is optional Parameter):** Specifies the GUID of the backup package that is to be restored. Each backup package has a unique GUID associated with it. The GUID can be seen by using the Get-SPBackupHistory cmdlet to view the backup history. If this parameter is not specified, the most recent backup package in the path that is specified with the Directory parameter is used.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607783.aspx

Comment: what about the -BackupId? what does this represents and from where i can get it ?

Comment: check the answer above,

Comment: now if i want to give the restored content database a new name inside the test machine , can i specify this using -item parameter? or i need to specify the original content database name inside the -item ? here is my current restore script "Restore-SPFarm -Directory T:\fileserver8\farm -RestoreMethod Overwrite -Item <can i specify a new name here !!> -Verbose" ??

Comment: honestly i am not sure about this, its long time, if i remember correctly you can give whatever name you want.

Comment: can you check my edit section inside my original question.. thanks

Comment: try with same name becuase i see thsi error " Item WSS_Content_copyLive not found"

Comment: but i define the restore method to be new !! so why the database need to be there..

Comment: try with existing name and then see the output

Comment: can you check my edit-2 section please?

Comment: i do not know what is going on seems when i do a farm restore on staging server it will try to create the database on the live DB as per the backuped content database ... as i got an error that content database named "WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8" already used...

Comment: try to put this parameter as well Restore-SPFarm -Directory T:\fileserver\farm -RestoreMethod new -Item  WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8  -NewDatabaseServer <String> -Verbose

Comment: so you mean in my previous method it was trying to create the database on the live server ? because when i click on enter insidethe cmd it start saying  that database server changed to our live Db server , then it said that "WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8" already exsits !!!

Comment: i guess yes that is the reason

Comment: Ok but can you please adivce on this , now when i start receiving this error :- "WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 already exists, please specify a new name" inside the cmd window, i close the cmd window,, so could i have negatively affect the live DB.. or what actually happened is that the restore command  tried to create  a new content data for the staging web application inside the live sql server,,but it failed since the database guid already exists ...

Comment: u are running this command on dev server, right?

Comment: yes i run the Restore-SPFarm on Dev .. but seems doing the restore in the way i did will try to Restore the content database on the live server ..now our Dev and live servers are on the same domain..

Comment: are you using the same service account in dev farm as that is in Production

Comment: yes they both have the same service accounts,,

Comment: this is big risk and not recommend...if you have separate set of services account for each farm then you can keep safe your production farm...

Comment: Yes this is correct, we are managing to do so.. but in my current case could i have negatively affect the live server,, now i checked the live site collections and every thing is working well ,,, but i am afraid that i might have done something wrong . although the last error i received when i try doing the restore "WSS_Content_ea05119bb8a4408ab450dcd46d6015e8 already exists, please specify a new name" which means it tried to create the DB but it failed is this correct ?

Comment: so it should not have done any thing on the live DB ..

Comment: your live farm is fine as of know, because it throws the error on start. But if you keep using the same account, you may hurt your prod...i.e if you use overwrite switch then it will overwrite the prod...now you can see the impact

Comment: yes you are 100% correct ,,now i have a full backup of  the live content database before i did the restore,, so i can take another backup of the  live content database, and compared them both ,, to see if anything was affected ,,, is there a way to do so ? second point seems the Restore-SPFarm does not allow  adding -NewDatabaseServer, so not sure how i can restore the live db inside the dev server ?

Comment: thats why in other post i recomend use the SQL backup and restore for teh cotent database

Comment: i did not get your point , why i need to use sql backup ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35755/discussion-on-answer-by-waqas-sarwar-mcse-restore-a-content-database-from-spbr00).